# Is there a canonical database of theorems?

Tags: reference-works

Does a (public) database of theorems exist, as integer sequences are cataloged in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)?

Comment: Wikipedia or Wolfram MathWorld are, somehow.

Comment: Wikipedia's [List of theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theorems) seems a good start.

Answer (score 12):

The Metamath Proof Explorer "... has over 12,000 completely worked out proofs ..." [[1]](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html#overview) accessible via an indexed theorem list. [[2]](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems.html)  Each theorem has a corresponding unique label.

The main Metamath page describes the project, the Metamath language, and programs and databases available for use. [[3]](http://us.metamath.org/)  The Metamath proofs are mechanical, and may or may not be useful because of their tedium and lack of insight.

An alternative to Metamath is Ghilbert [[4]](http://ghilbert-app.appspot.com/), which looks much nicer.  For example, contrast the Ghilbert proof of Euclid's Theorem [[5]](http://ghilbert-app.appspot.com/edit/peano/peano_thms.gh/euclidthm) with the Metamath proof of infinitely many primes. [[6]](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems99.html#mm9884s)  Unfortunately, Ghilbert does not seem to have an indexed database of theorems like Metamath does.

Some ad hoc lists of theorems that do not include canonical identifiers are:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theorems
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_proofs
- http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/geometry/GPB/theorems.htm

The [Cut the Knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/) and [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/) web sites are worth mentioning, if only because they have extensive collections of mathematical resources, many theorems included.

The following is a list of some related answers on math.SE. However, these answers did not address a canonical indexing of the theorems.

- [The most common theorems taught in Abstract Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105285/the-most-common-theorems-taught-in-abstract-algebra)
- [Does anybody know of a site that has a set of all theorems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149657/does-anybody-know-of-a-site-that-has-a-set-of-all-theorems)

References:

- [1] http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html#overview
- [2] http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems.html (inline GIF images) and http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems.html (unicode)
- [3] http://us.metamath.org/
- [4] http://ghilbert-app.appspot.com/
- [5] http://ghilbert-app.appspot.com/edit/peano/peano_thms.gh/euclidthm
- [6] http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems99.html#mm9884s

Answer (score 5):

I might also add that [ProofWiki](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a community project to do such, complete with proofs.